# Emacs "error in process filter: menu-bar-update-yank-menu: Wrong type argument: stringp, nil"

Tags: emacs, elisp

I maintain a elisp project at https://github.com/coordinate/bingapiel.

It is for translating with bing api in emacs.

Some users complain about that error :

```
error in process filter: menu-bar-update-yank-menu: Wrong type argument: stringp, nil
error in process filter: Wrong type argument: stringp, nil
```

But I can not reproduce the error on my computer.

So I'm here for help. Did anyone encountered this error too. Does anyone know the meaning of "menu-bar-update-yank-menu: Wrong type argument: stringp, nil". Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

might result from a hook, which isn't fed as expected
for example the buffer is killed inter-course

lines 128-131 bing-translate.el look strange for me

```
    (with-current-buffer buf
      (let* ((xmldata (decode-coding-string (buffer-string) 'utf-8))
             (result nil))
        (kill-buffer (current-buffer))
        (when (equal "expired" (bingapi-check-accesstoken xmldata))
          ;; get secend time
          (setq buf (url-retrieve-synchronously
                     (bingtranslate-make-url
                      "GetLanguagesForTranslate?" nil)))
          (if buf
```

;;;;

i.e. current-buf "buf" is killed,
set again later on "when"
but only "when"

in not, following if runs empty (?)

just as it looks at a first glance...

Comment: Thanks Andreas Röhler. You are right. With "with-current-buffer" I don't need kill-buffer anymore. And I would like to know did you add bingapiel to your emacs? Did it work fine?